# Zend form create dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, forms, zend-framework, dynamic, subform

i am new to Zend framework and what i would like to to is to create a form which except from the simple input and select fields will also incorporate addition of multiple input fields with jquery eg:
[image: Multiple input fields]

and another form element which could accept multiple pairs of select and input like this:
[image: Multiple pairs of select and input]

Those will be inserted at client side using jquery. How can i implement this at Zend using the form element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done what you're trying to achieve in some projects and the best approach I've found is to use subforms. Here's some guidelines that might help you.

**Config the parent form**

```
public function __construct($wine = null)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->setName('parent-form'); // you can set any name
    $this->setIsArray(true);
    $this->_initForm();
}
```

**Add as many subform you need inside your form**

```
protected function _initForm(){
    $this->clearSubForms();
    $subForm = new Application_Form_Subform(1);
    $subForm->removeDecorator('Form');
    $this->addSubform($subForm,'subform-'.1);

    $subForm = new Application_Form_Subform(2);
    $subForm->removeDecorator('Form');
    $this->addSubform($subForm,'subform-'.2);
}
```

**Config the subform**

```
public function __construct($key) {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setElementsBelongTo("parentform[subform][$key]");
    $this->setIsArray(true)->setName("subform")->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');

    $this->_initForm();
}
```

**Echo the subforms on your form view**

```
<?php
    foreach($this->element->getSubforms() as $key => $subForm){
        echo $subForm;
    }
?>
```

**Dynamically add elements on your form view using Jquery**

I'm not gonna provide any code here. But what I usually do is to add a hidden template for the subform so I can clone from it. What you have to do also, is to adjust the indexes of the name attibute on the inputs of the subform.

**Getting the data on controller**

```
if ($request->isPost()) {

    $data = $request->getPost('parentform');

    if ($form->isValid($data)) {
        foreach ($data['subform'] as $subformInfo) { // loop through each subform input
          // do something with your data
        }
    }
```